# Edit elasticsearch as a table using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I don't ask a question rather than ask for advice. 
I have the elasticsearch index in my project (fields are more-less static and well-structured). 
I somehow need to edit this index using python and frontend. Like excel table.

So I can create the frontend and backend using Flask and other modules. However, I am struggling with the architecture.

My idea is:
1. Flask frontend asks and shows data using flask-excel or something else. 
2. Backend saves this data into the buffer csv-file. 
3. When the user is clicking "Save", Backend will save this csv into the elastic.

But it seems so rude and unlogical.

Maybe you guys could help me to start this project. Any recommendation would be great.

Thank you and sorry for so inaccurate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) in the backend.[Es-Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/es-pandas/) for indexing the CSV into ElasticSearch.
Pandas will be easy for handling CSV/excel etc. Convert the CSV to a data frame and then indexing to ElasticSearch can be done using es-pandas.